# How to fadeIn element on page load instead of "appear"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a really huge noob on jquery, I need to figure out how to change this code:

```
$('.social li').appear();
$(document.body).on('appear', '.social li', function(e, $affected) {
    var fadeDelayAttr;
    var fadeDelay;
    $(this).each(function(){


        if ($(this).data("delay")) {
            fadeDelayAttr = $(this).data("delay")
            fadeDelay = fadeDelayAttr;              
        } else {
            fadeDelay = 0;
        }           
        $(this).delay(fadeDelay).queue(function(){
            $(this).addClass('animated').clearQueue();
        });         
    })          
});
```

to work in the way that it would start animation as soon as someone enters the landing page, right now it works good on everything besides IE10 and IE11, was told to change it to load by default not on "appear" but I tried document ready/load and I can't get it to work...

Comment: can u give a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F9We7/ this is jsfiddle, hope it makes it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try fading all list items into view, each with a progessing 250ms delay:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('.social li').hide().each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay((i + 1) * 250).fadeIn(2000);
   });
});
```

**EDIT**:

Using the same logic as your previous code to refactor, use the `window.load` method since the load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames etc have finished loading. So use this event to do the fading in animation of the list items into view, where their initial state will be hidden.

You have two variables declared `fadeDelayAttr` and `fadeDelay` but I noticed that only `fadeDelay` is being used, so `fadeDelayAttr` can be discarded. Also, this part of the code:

```
   if ($(this).data("delay")) {
        fadeDelayAttr = $(this).data("delay")
        fadeDelay = fadeDelayAttr;              
    } else {
        fadeDelay = 0;
    }
```

can be simplified as the null-coalescing operator using a logical `OR (||)`:

```
var fadeDelay = $(this).data("delay") || 0;
```

Since the fadeDelay variable gets its value from the data-delay attribute, this can then be passed in as an argument for the delay method and finally the refactored code will look like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.social li').hide().each(function() {
        var fadeDelay = $(this).data("delay") || 0; 
        $(this).delay(fadeDelay).fadeIn(2000);
   });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/F7Ky7/)**

Comment: I am sorry, I am too noob to do that, how to edit the script i posted or where to add yours and should i remove mine then?